# Optimizing CSV to MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I've tried this in PHP and now MYSQL and both outcomes seem to execute in around 15 seconds with 100 different items.  This procedure takes at CSV variable and inserts only the records that aren't currently in the database.  After this each item is inserted into the order_items_part_numbers tables with the corresponding order item id.  Here is the code I currently have.  Any help making this faster would be appreciated.

```
PROCEDURE `add_part_number_to_item_mysql`(_order_items_id INT, _part_numbers VARCHAR(5000))
BEGIN

DECLARE _part_number VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE _existing_part_number_id INT;

WHILE _part_numbers IS NOT NULL DO
SET _part_number = (SELECT CASE LOCATE(";", _part_numbers, 1)
 WHEN 0 THEN _part_numbers -- empty or single word
 ELSE SUBSTRING(_part_numbers, 1, LOCATE(";", _part_numbers, 1) - 1) -- multi-word
END);

SET _part_number = TRIM(_part_number);

SET _existing_part_number_id = (SELECT ID FROM inventory WHERE item_number = _part_number);

IF _existing_part_number_id IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO inventory (item_number) VALUES (UPPER(_part_number));
SET _existing_part_number_id = @@IDENTITY;
END IF;

INSERT INTO order_items_part_numbers (order_items_id, inventory_id) VALUES (_order_items_id, _existing_part_number_id);


SET _part_numbers = (SELECT CASE LOCATE(";", _part_numbers, 1)
 WHEN 0 THEN NULL -- empty or single word
 ELSE SUBSTRING(_part_numbers, LOCATE(";", _part_numbers)+1) -- multi-word
 END);

SET _part_numbers = TRIM(_part_numbers);
END WHILE;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeatedly running `LOCATE` with the same parameter values, store the output in a local variable and use where needed.

If you used the exact same algorithm in php, I'd suggest using `explode()` and then looping through the resulting array instead.

Comment: I did use explode() in PHP and it didn't speed things up.  Also, the variable changes each time LOCATE is used so it's not really being used on the same variable.

Comment: In a single loop, it's the same variable, is it not?

Comment: Because LOCATE is being run on _part_numbers which changes with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, i meant single iteration, sorry, you are running `LOCATE` four times in each iteration with no difference at all.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'll give that a shot.